# how to display an alert box after successful registration and at the same time clear text boxes after the alert box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, view

here is the code for my Controller Below i tried to do the method for alert box but when i add the one for clearing text boxes my alert box message stop completeley to show. please anyone who knows how i can go about this help.

```
     // GET: User
    public ActionResult Register()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterClient U)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                try {
                    User newone = new User();

                    newone.EmailID = U.EmailID;
                    newone.Name = U.Name;
                    newone.Surname = U.Surname;
                    newone.Contact_Nr = U.Contact_Nr;
                    newone.Department = U.Department;
                    db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(newone);

                    db.SubmitChanges();




                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = e.Message;
                }
                code
                ViewData["Message"] = "Successful Registration.";


                return View();

            };

            }

        return View(U);
    }
```

here is the code for my View

```
       @{
            ViewBag.Title = "now registered";
        }

        <h2></h2>
        @if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
        {
            <script language="javascript">
alert('@ViewData["Message"]');
            </script>
        }
```

Comment: Just call reset your textboxes after alert. If you want to have a callback function trigger after you click OK, so dont use the default alert. Use a dialog instead, such as bootbox... or something like that.

Comment: Thanks @HenryTran can you help me with the code please ModelState.Clear(); didn't work which other code for reset?

Comment: If you had a form (assumed it has an id), you could call `$('#your_form_id').reset();`. If you had no form, then try to reset each type of your controls, like this: $('input, select').val('') ...

Comment: @HenryTran where do i put this code, I'm sorry I'm not that advanced in C# and MVC. its giving me errors or maybe i have put it in the rong place. i placed it after my alert box message ViewData["Message"] = "Successful Registration."; before my return statement

Comment: It's javascript code. You can put it inside <script> ... </script>. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: thanx so much @HenryTran your code was helpful

Comment: Welcome. Happy coding!